# rspec stub a method in an already imp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a method (send_to) on model that I want to avoid be called during one specific test. But it always got executed.

Im doing this.

```
subject { create(:batch_with_jobs) } #Batch hasMany Jobs
...
it 'raise if all jobs are not in right state' do
  Job.stub(:sent_to){true} #first attempt, doesnt work
  Job.any_instance.stub(:sent_to).and_return(true)  #second attempt, doesnt work

  subject.jobs.first.update_attribute :state, :error_submitting
  expect{subject.commit}.to raise_error
end
```

the commit method continue executing the original send_to method.

EDIT: YES, ISSUE IS BECAUSE I WAS STUBING SENT_TO AND IT SHOULD BE SEND_TO.

Comment: Your question states the method is called `send_to`, but your code stubs `sent_to`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the syntax as such. though personally I'd add a context and do stub /unstub in before and after blocks. Other than that hard to say without seeing the relevant code for JOb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two comments on your code.

1. As @fivedigit says, you stub `sent_to`, but claim the method is named `send_to`.
2. Your spec description is difficult to read, maybe some thing like "raises an error when no jobs have the right state" or "raises an error when all jobs have the wrong state".

Comment: You are right, sent_to is invalid, should I delete the question?

Comment: No, these kinds of mistakes are pretty common (e.g. we all make typos and need others to point them out to us). I always find it comforting to see others have the same problem :-)